# Retrieve image from area

Tags: area, image, imagery

I'm looking for a way to retrieve an image (a satellite one, preferably) from a rectangular area of a map given a minimum and maximum latitude/longitude.
What tools can I use to achieve this?

Comment: There are many different satellites and just as many sources of retrieving data. You'd need to decide on which imagery source that you are after. Perhaps consider freely available data sources, such as Sentinel-2 or Landsat 8. If Sentinel-2 is suitable for your needs, consider using the python package 'sentinelsat' for your data-fetching needs

Comment: I was looking for a service similar to [this one](http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/export) but with better quality and without any labels

Comment: The terminology that you are looking for is a Web Map Service (WMS). There are many different ones, so it would depend on your application and needs.